# MySQL datatype to store one of two options

Tags: mysql

I have been looking at the datatypes for MySQL but there is nothing really that I can see that mandates that input is either one thing or another. E.g. "option1" or "option2".

How might I do something like this when creating a table?

Comment: Can you be more specific? What kind of data you have?

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/de/enum.html ? Bool ?

Comment: this field is used to distinguish between administrators and general users. So the field type can only be set to "admin" or "user" and nothing else.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use enum datatype for restricting input within a range of values. Below is a sample table that shows the usage.

```
CREATE TABLE Sample 
    (
     id int auto_increment primary key, 
     options enum('option1', 'option2')
    );
```

The options field will only accept NULL, option1 OR option2 values. However, you can mark it NOT NULL as well.

You can further read the doco [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/enum.html)